# Awareness Fence API:- LocationFence not working, Fence registered successfully but Broadcast Receiver failed to receive any thing

Tags: android, geolocation, geofencing, google-awareness

I am trying to register Fence LocationFence API for tracking the user enters, exit or IN in a particular location, The Fence was register successfully but the registered Broadcast receiver failed to catch any ***`LocationFence.in , LocationFence.entering or LocationFence.exiting`***
Is I'm missing something?(my location is in INDIA +5:30 GMT).
Please find below my code:-

NOTE: I tried fences with HeadphoneFence.pluggingIn and HeadphoneFence.unplugging and able to get both events in same broadcast receiver.

```
private final String FENCE_LOCATION_RECEIVER_ACTION =
            BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + "FENCE_LOCATION_RECEIVER_ACTION";

Intent intent1 = new Intent(FENCE_LOCATION_RECEIVER_ACTION);
  mLocationPendingIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this,0,intent1, 0);



FenceLocationReceiver fenceLOcationReceiver = new FenceLOcationReceiver();
     registerReceiver(fenceLOcationReceiver, new IntentFilter(FENCE_LOCATION_RECEIVER_ACTION));

      checkLocationPermission();
            AwarenessFence myFence = AwarenessFence.or(LocationFence.in(28.557659, 77.2459485, 10, 60000L), LocationFence.entering(28.557659, 77.2459485, 10), LocationFence.exiting(28.557659, 77.2459485, 10));
            Awareness.FenceApi.updateFences(
                    mGoogleApiClient,
                    new FenceUpdateRequest.Builder()
                            .addFence(LOCATION_FENCE_KEY, myFence, mLocationPendingIntent)
                            .build())
                    .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
                            if (status.isSuccess()) {
                                Log.i(TAG, "here location Fence was successfully registered.");
                            } else {
                                Log.e(TAG, "here location Fence could not be registered: " + status);
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

Here is my Broadcast Receiver code:-

```
public class FenceLocationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (!TextUtils.equals(FENCE_LOCATION_RECEIVER_ACTION, intent.getAction())) {
            txt.setText("Received an unsupported action in FenceReceiver: action="
                    + intent.getAction());
            return;

        }
        // The state information for the given fence is em
        FenceState fenceState = FenceState.extract(intent);

        if (TextUtils.equals(fenceState.getFenceKey(), FENCE_LOCATION_RECEIVER_ACTION)) {
            String fenceStateStr;
            switch (fenceState.getCurrentState()) {
                case FenceState.TRUE:
                    fenceStateStr = "true";
                    txt.setText(fenceStateStr);
                    break;
                case FenceState.FALSE:

                    fenceStateStr = "false";
                    txt.setText(fenceStateStr);

                    break;
                case FenceState.UNKNOWN:
                    fenceStateStr = "unknown";
                    txt.setText(fenceStateStr);

                    break;
                default:
                    fenceStateStr = "unknown value";
                    txt.setText(fenceStateStr);

            }
            txt.setText("Fence state:" + fenceStateStr);
        }
    }
}
```

Here permissions defined in Manifest:-

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION" />
```

Comment: Did you add the Broadcastreceiver to your manifest?

Comment: Yes, i also try with that too, by adding BroadcastReceiver in mainfest instead of registering it programatically. but no luck :(

Comment: Try making the BroadcastReceiver explicit rather than implicit. Don't use the action tag.